# .htaccess adding trailing slashes

Tags: regex, html, apache, .htaccess

I am a beginner web dev and I am attempting to convert one of my old wordpress sites into a vanilla JS/HTML and CSS website.

The URLs on my wordpress site began with www and had trailing slashes at the end of every url (other than the home page). I have been attempting different commands via the .htaccess file I created and I managed to successfully remove the .html extensions from my pages and add the www prefix. However, despite numerous tries (I have tried around twelve different snippets that I found on this website and others) I have not been able to add trailing slashes to the URLs.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

The following is my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Could you add examples of an old url, compared to a "new" url? You managed to add `.html` to a request given - why can't you manage to add `/`?